# Xcode - ERROR ITM-90039: Type Mismatch using swift cannot validate/export app

Tags: ios, xcode

Every time I try to validate, export, or submit my app to the appstore I get the following error

[image: Error]

I feel like I have literally tried everything to fix it and CANT so ANY help would be greatly appreciated. I have read every single other entry on this site and none of the answers work for me.

Comment: Just go through the error message consciously & you will get the solution.

Comment: @iYoung Thanks for the help but I'm not sure what you mean as I have gone through the error message and gone to the url and reread and redone basically everything. This is the third day I have been working on this one error and rereading the error message doesn't help me.